# Perl execution failed error when adding a virtual host in Webmin

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm getting the following error when I try to select the document root when creating a virtual host in Webmin.

Error:

**Directory of /
HTTP/1.0 500 Perl execution failed Server: MiniServ/1.700 Date: Tue, 9 Sep 2014 20:39:29 GMT Content-type: text/html; Charset=iso-8859-1 Connection: close
Error - Perl execution failed
Undefined subroutine &main::quote_javascript called at /usr/share/webmin/chooser.cgi line 192.**

This started happening after I took a few steps to secure Webmin. I changed the Webmin and SSH ports. I also created a new sudo user and disallowed root access via SSH and Webmin. I am using Debian 7.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Arthur, would be useful to have your configuration settings to better help you on this.

Comment: This is a known bug in Webmin 1.7, I found a fix on the webmin site for it but its a development package and I have not installed it as I want to wait for stable. www.webmin.com IS listing this as a known problem though - its not down to anything you have done!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I ended up downgrading to 1.670.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Download the 1.701 Fix package and upload it manually if you really need this functionality. Here is the [Link to Webmin Dev Downloads](http://www.webmin.com/devel.html) but I don't recommend it until its a stable release. The error can be circumnavigated by simply entering the paths / values directly if you know them.

Comment: I downgraded to 1.670, but I will play around with that. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried that patch yet - did you try it @ArthurWalker? I am unhappy about downgrading but have since found I too need that popup explorer to work for the Filesystem Backups Explorer!!!